# AngularJS - trustAsHtml. Help Me Understand

Tags: angularjs

I've been at this for too long.
Basically, I'm pulling information via json. 
This works fine, but the information being pulled does not show up as HTML.

I've been trying to get trustAsHtml to work but I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

Controller:

```
    var pageControllers = angular.module('pageControllers', ['ngSanitize']);

pageControllers.controller('PackagesCtrl', function PackagesCtrl($scope, $sce, $http){
                           $http.get('scripts/all_packages.php').success(function(data){ 

                            $scope.packagesData = data; 

                           });
});
```

I'm getting groups of data from the database fine. My data is rendering pure text instead of showing the actual html eg: `<p class="myClass">My Returned Data</p>`

My Html has an `ng-repeat="item in packagesData"`

and in that div I have:

`ng-bind-html="item.more_info"`.

This returns the data I need, but how would I now make them render properly? Basically, from the returned fields, I need 2 results to show up as html, but everything I try does not work.

My json file returns multiple rows of data, e.g.:

```
[{"title":"My Title", "more_info":"<p>Information</p>"},{"title":"My Title 2", "more_info":"<p>Information 2</p>"}]
```

How do I target specific results such as "more_info" to show as html?

Comment: What does the returned JSON look like? How are you displaying it in the view? Show us your code.

Comment: Can we see the where you're trying to bind the returned html?

Comment: @JB Nizet, thanks for the response. The JSON is pretty standard. I updated the post. I already posted how I display the results in the html. I have a div with an ng-repeat and I inside the repeated divs I have p tags with ng-bind-html="item.more_info". I just need to know the final step in the controller to make it render "more_info" properly. I tried many different tutorials for trustAsHtml(); I removed the code in the controller because they did not work. Looking at the code provided, what would you add in the controller? Thanks.

Comment: @user1828415 Not seeing any obvious problems here. Can you post a complete version of your HTML rather than describing it? Or even better would be to create a fiddle showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

basically you right on your path. What you need to do is to check if its the right value with key. Key is you identifier for particular value. 
The thing you need to do is to use an ng-if condition.

```
<h2 ng-if="key=='more_info'" ng-bind-html="value"></h2>
```